# Why CakePHP is not allowing to create MySQL table names without plural?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Putting "_ underscore" is old school. Why CakePHP is using it till now. And also why CakePHP is not allowing to create MySQL table names without plural. Is this mandatory ?

Comment: Why is it old school? Please bring some technical argument. And why didn't you read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions? By the way, Eloquent does it exactly the same "old" way.

Comment: Didn't you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default naming convention for cakephp. If you don't want to use default then use this method

For cakephp 3 [details here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html)

```
$this->setTable('my_table');

// Prior to 3.4.0
$this->table('my_table');
```

For cakephp 2 [details here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable)

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'exmp'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
}
```